# c# - Can I retain the format for cells when copying excel sheets using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, copy, excel-interop

I have some code that copies all sheets from one excel file into another. This code is as follows:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook source = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook destination = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(missing);
string file = @"C:\SomeExcelFile.xlsx";

source = ExcelApp.Workbooks._Open
(file, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing
, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet s in source.Worksheets)
{
    s.Copy(Type.Missing, destination.Worksheets[destination.Worksheets.Count]);
}
```

In most cases this works as expected but there are two issues that I want to resolve. The first is that in one of the excel workbooks I am copying there is a column that is formatted like this:

`$#,##0.00;[Red]-$#,##0.00`

When running this through my code this column gets reformatted to this:

```
$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)
```

Is there a way I can retain the formatting of the original file?

Secondly, I'd like the widths of the columns to remain the same as the original file. Is this possible too?

This code is being used to merge multiple excel workbooks into a single file.

Thanks

Comment: Why you just dont copy the whole excel instead of copying cells ?

Comment: This code is actually used to merge multiple excel workbooks into a single workbook. Also, I am copying sheets, not cells.

Comment: i would recommend you to use [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) for managing excel, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044854/how-to-copy-excelworksheet-from-template-with-new-codemodule) thread seems to be similar.